# checking whether Entry is empty or not in a python Tkinter program

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have an Entry in a python program in which i want my users to enter a URL. my first task is to check whether user entered a value or not. I'v used the following code but it's not working as expected.

my entry name is `txtUrl`

```
if(txtUrl.get() == ""):
    tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", "please enter a url")
```

if user entered a url then show the next window

```
else:
    webCrawl=Tk()

    #and other widgets in it
```

This is how I create the `txtUrl` widget

```
self.txtUrl=Entry(self)
self.txtUrl["width"]=60
self.txtUrl.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = EW)
```

I also tried to use this line

```
self.txtUrl["textvariable"]=content
```

and tried to get the value as below and check for its emptiness but it didn't work too

```
if(content.get()==""):
    tkMessageBox.showerror("Error","please enter a url")
```

someone please let me know how to check for it. I'm trying to do a similar task done by a required field validator in asp.net

Comment: When you say "it's not working as expected", what's it doing? Does it throw an error? Does it return a string that's not in the widget? Does it always return None or an empty string? Does python crash?

Comment: Why do you create another Tk instance? "webCrawl=Tk()"

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your question to answer. You say something isn't working but you don't say what that means. The specific line of code you say isn't working looks syntactically correct. So, unless you can be more specific about what behavior or errors you are getting, there's no way we can help.

You have another crucial error in your code which may be contributing to the problem. Specifically, the line where you do `else: webCrawl=Tk()`. You should never need to create more than a single instance of Tk during the course of a program. If all you're doing is creating more windows, create an instance of `Toplevel`.